# Ubuntu phone not recognized by OSX

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

As stated in the title, my bq Aquaris 4.5 is not recognized by my laptop running Yosemite (OSX 10.10.5).

Other laptop running Windows 7 recognizes device and allows browsing of folders.

Does anyone know why and how to access the device through OSX?

Additional info:
Phone is running 15.04.
Close to 0 experience with Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options,

1) Install **Android File Transfer** on your **Mac** for browse and transfer files **(up to 4GB)** between your Ubuntu Phone and Mac. ([Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/))

2) Install **WifiTransfer** on your **Ubuntu Phone** (from Ubuntu Store) for browse and transfer files between your phone and Mac **without cable** over **FTP**. ([WifiTransfer](https://uappexplorer.com/app/wifitransfer.sil))

Kind regards

Comment: Thank you, this seems to suffice. Still curious as to the reason this happens, though.

Comment: You're welcome! Our bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition and also E5 and meizu MX4 are all recycled Android device and using MTP (Read more at Wikipedia, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)) that allows files to be transferred to and from portable devices. OS X has not driver to mount MTP devices as drives. Android File Transfer is a simple MTP client for OS X.